# Disabled textbox on Microsoft Edge is not selectable

Tags: css, textbox, microsoft-edge, html-input

In my webpage, I need a disabled textbox to show content (very long).

```
<input disabled type="text" value="a very long long long text...">
```

In Chrome, we can select the text in the disabled input to scroll to view all content.
However, In MS Edge, it seems that the disabled textbox is not selectable, therefore, it cannot be scrolled to view entire content.
Is there anyway to customize CSS to select text on disabled textbox on Ms Edge.

Comment: Perhaps `readonly` would be more suitable than `disabled` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually content is selectable from disabled textbox in Edge but it will not scroll like it scrolls in Chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="">
 
  Text : <input type="text" name="txt1" value="Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries." disabled><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in Edge browser:

[image]

So if your requirement is to select the text than it is possible as you can see in my testing result.

If your requirement is to scroll the content then at present it is not possible with MS Edge browser. As a work around, you can try to use **read only** instead of **disabled** as already suggested by @Turnip. It will allow user to scroll the text in textbox.

I will try to submit the feedback to Microsoft via our internal channel regarding this issue.

Comment: I can select whole text in the input, however, I cannot use mouse to select a part of the text (for example: press mouse at 2nd character, and release mouse at 5th characters)

Comment: The work around can be to set the background color of textbox same as disabled textbox and use read only attribute. So in appearance it looks like it is disabled and still user can select and scroll the text.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT thanks for the information. Is this issue fixed now? Can you please help me how I can handle this here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-disabling-edge

Comment: @app, it looks like disabled input does not get scrolled in the MS Edge legacy browser. If possible for you then you can use the latest MS Edge Chromium browser to avoid the issue. If you need to use the Edge legacy browser then as a workaround you can replace the input with the textarea control. It will have the scroll functionality when it is disabled. If you can't replace the input control then another workaround you can develop a logic to display the input text on hover may help in this issue.