# input form group disable text selection scroll not working for longer text in Microsoft edge

Tags: html, css, angular, input, disabled-input

I am trying to access the longer text in the Microsoft edge when input is in disable mode but somehow I am not able to select the input at all in the edge.

This feature is working fine in chrome and edge.

Anyone has faced same issue like this before?

edge:
[image]

chrome/IE:
[image]

below is reproducible stackblitz code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-disabling-edge

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabled textbox on Microsoft Edge is not selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658483/disabled-textbox-on-microsoft-edge-is-not-selectable)

Comment: OK, I just saw that you also left a comment there. In any case, it looks like this is still an issue because this is reproducible with any disabled input, not just your link using Angular.